# Having a function perform a different action if an idex is out of range?

Tags: python, function

```
result1= r_record1.annotations['accessions'][1]
result2 = r_record1.annotations['accessions'][0]
s_handle1= Entrez.esummary(db='nucleotide', id=**result1 or result2**, rettype='gb', retmode='text')
s_record1= Entrez.read(s_handle1)
```

This code is from a body of a function I am writing.  Essentially I am parsing through records and need to pull an ID from a list, but very few of the 100's of records I am going through only have one item in a list.  Most records need the second item in the list (first line) but few need the first record (line 2).  Is there a way i can input into line 3 a way to choose the first result1 and if index out of range choose result 2 (bold)?

Comment: `len` function returns the number of items in a list so you can choose what to do based on this value.

Comment: Why not just take the last item: `result= r_record1.annotations['accessions'][-1]`

Answer (score 0):

In response to the question in the title of your post, you would want to do the following:

```
try:
     # your code here for choosing the "first result1"
except IndexError:
     # your code here for choosing "result 2 (bold)"
```

You may want to learn more about [try/except exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) in Python. In particular, the error you are handling here is an [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError).

What I suspect you *actually* want is to look at the length of your `annotations['accessions']` list for each record (using `len(r_record1.annotations['accessions'])`) and then do the appropriate `[0]` or `[1]` access accordingly.